# check if checkbox in span is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, checkbox, each

I have a small .each() loop that checks if span is visible, i'd like to then check if a checkbox is checked or not witin that span tag.

function is

```
function processReports(){
    $("#processedReports").html('');
    var repName = $("#reviewType").val();   
    var divHTML = "<table style='width: 300px;'><tr><td style='width:30%; text-align:left; font-weight:bold;'>Report</td><td style='font-weight:bold; width:50%; text-align:right; padding-right:4px;'>Date/Time Run</td><td style='font-weight:bold;'>Progress</td></tr>";
    var d = new Date();
    var strDate =  (d.getMonth()+1) + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear();
    var strTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    $("#reportChecks span:visible").each(function(){
        var reportName = $(this).attr("reportType");
        **if($('input.checkbox').is(':checked')){**
            divHTML += "<tr><td style='width:30%; text-align:left;' class='" + reportName +"' advID='" + $(this).text() + "'>" + reportName + "</td><td style='width:50%; text-align:right; padding-right:4px;'>" + strDate + "," + strTime + "</td><td><a href='/Applications/help/Reports/Prospect_reports/Prospect1ClickReview.pdf' target='_blank'>View</a></td></tr>";
        }
        //alert($(this).text());
    });
    divHTML += "</table>";
    $("#processedReports").prepend(divHTML);
    $("#processedReports").show();
    $("#IndReports").show();
}
```

basically where i have if($('input.checkbox').is('checked')){...... doesn't work.  The span tags only have the single checkbox within them, so all i want to do is know if that element is checked or not, if it is append the divHTML if not, continue through the loop
thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with the [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) value:

```
if($(this).find('.checkbox').prop('checked'))
```

With no assignment, this returns a boolean for the value it has. It's also faster than `.is(':checked')`:

[jsPerf comparing `.is(':checked')` and `.prop('checked')`](http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked/5)

Of course, if there is only one checkbox, you could use the vanilla JS way:

```
if($(this).find('.checkbox')[0].checked)
```

This is faster by a large margin, also seen in the jsPerf provided.

Answer (score 1):

You need to search the descendant of current span object to get the input within it. You can use `find()` or pass `this` in context of selector. If you use context it will be translated to find() so I would prefer using find. I assume .checkbox is class of checkbox element you are trying to access.

*Using find()*

```
if($(this).find('input.checkbox').is(':checked'))
```

If `checkbox` is **not** class but type then

```
if($(this).find(':checkbox').is(:checked'))
```

*Using context*

```
if($('input.checkbox', this).is(':checked'))
```

Comment: this is a type, i used a combination of both answers, using .prop rather than .is() and using your find method with the checkbox type, wish i could accept both as answers.  thank you both!